# positioning text on top of the container

Tags: html, css

I am breaking my head on how I can position the highlighted element in the marked position.

[Image of the site with the highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJtt2.png)

[image]

Also, I can't find any way to make the items position evenly in the container; instead, three are at the top, and one is in the bottom.

```css
.cards__title {
  justify-content: center;
}

.cards {
  background-color: #363636;
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: #EEEBDD;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="cards">
  <h2 class="cards__tile">Lorem Ipsum</h2>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card__img">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card__img">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card__img">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <img class="card__img">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried using space evenly on the container, but that just breaks all the items.

Comment: You need width:100% and text-align:center on the item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have in your html code the class 'cards__tile' for that h2 and in the css code 'cards__title'. Secondly, you can add a width: 100% or a flex-basis: 100%